# Meaning of the letter 

Tags: affine-geometry, polyhedra, polytopes

I've seen $\mathbb{K}$ in a few places defining affine function without a definition, wondering what it means. For [example](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~pouchet/doc/pouchet-phdthesis.pdf):

A function $f : \mathbb{K}^m \to \mathbb{K}^n$ is affine if there exists a vector $\vec{b} \in \mathbb{K}^n$ and a matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{m\times n}$ such that:

$$\forall\vec{x} \in \mathbb{K}^m, f(\vec{x}) = A\vec{x}+\vec{b}$$

Comment: In the cases I am familiar with (mainly in functional analysis), $\mathbb{K}$ is understood to be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and is used when the results being proved apply to both real and complex vector spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $\mathbb{K}$ is just a variable, like any other.  It does not have any fixed meaning.

However, it is traditional to use the letter $k$ (and variants of it) to denote fields.  So, $\mathbb{K}$ would usually denote some particular field which is fixed throughout what you are doing.  It's rather lazy to just start using it with such a meaning without including a line like "Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field", though.

Answer (score 1):

It usually stands for field. It comes from German word Körper.

From wikipedia:

> In $1871$ Richard Dedekind introduced, for a set of real or complex numbers which is closed under the four arithmetic operations, the German word Körper, which means "body" or "corpus" (to suggest an organically closed entity).  The English term "field" was introduced by Moore (1893)